# iOS Table Views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Using just theTable Views, I added a label to the first cell, I tried to drag it to the view controller to ad code, but it didn't work. (Still very new to programming)

This is all that's in the view controller now.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath index, Path: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        return
    }
}
```

Also for this, I get "parameter requires an explicit type error

```
func tableView(_tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath index, Path: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return
}
```

Comment: did you assigned a class to a view controller??

Comment: You are not returning anything in a method that requires you return a `UITableViewCell`. You should go and find a tutorial on how to use `UITableView` in iOS. It will help you... a lot.

Comment: can you recommend a video ? I was following a video on how to do this and it wasn't until I couldn't add a label that I got stuck

Comment: You must take help from a tutorial...Theres a lot thing to be done like assigning class to cells, then accessing cell label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and you can refer this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCSGh-YJgvs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a class to a view controller and you have to return a UITableViewCell. once class is provided select lable and drag it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, be sure to assign the class of the view controller in the storyboards, otherwise, Xcode doesn't allow you to create @IBOutlets by dragging the label.

The second one, the function is expected to return a **UITableViewCell**, and you're not returning anything. Also, if you're using Swift 3, this is the new syntax. A quick fix for you to check would be the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class of type  UITableViewCell

```
  class sampleCell: UITableViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var _myLabel: UILabel! // you have to drag from  story board.
  }
```

//Storybord

select the cell where you put the label.

click on the cell -> select identity inspecter -> custom class ->set the custom class name. // "sampleCell"

select the next tab attribute inspector -> identifier set the name as "sampleCell" // you can put any name

//ViewController

set outlet tableview.

```
     @IBOutlet weak var _tableView: UITableView! // drag from viewcontroller

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = _tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sampleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! sampleCell
    cell._myLabel.text = "sample"
    return cell
  }
```